# Showing the continuity of a function based on the continuity of another function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, continuity, closed-map

I am having a bit of trouble seeing why the following $f_\epsilon$ is continuous.

Be $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ bounded and closed and $f : M \to \mathbb{R}^k $ continuous, then for a $\epsilon > 0$  is: 
$$f_\epsilon = sup\{\delta > 0 | f(B(x,\delta))\cap M \subset B(f(x),\epsilon) \}$$
also continuous, but why is that?

P.S. the definition for continuity we're using is $\forall x \in M: \forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: f(B(x,\delta)) \subset B(f(x),\epsilon)$

Comment: Can you clarify by saying a  bound for $\delta$, ? 

For constant function on compact subset that Supremum is $+ \infty$
Shouldn't $\delta  \leq \text{diam} M $

Comment: no bounds for $\delta$ were given, that is my problem.

Comment: take $f=0$ on $R$ and $M$ is any subset of $R$ then $f_{\epsilon} = \infty$ !

Comment: First the edit you just made doesn't make any sense, secondly if you write $f(B(x, \delta)\cap M)$ still it has same problem. $f_{\epsilon}$ can be $\infty$